# R Shiny : Issue with the output name and for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, shiny, output

I am trying to assign a R shiny output name in a for loop. My code split a text and check for each element if it a contain the word “table”, it often looks like “table1” “table2”. Then it search for the corresponding dataframe based of the number of the table with the function fun_extract_table (located in the file main.R, don’t need to show the file). The dataframe is send to a renderTable. But for some reason, in the shiny app, it returns always the same dataframe and the last iteration of the loop.

Here is the code.

Server.R

```
library(shiny)
source("main.R", local = TRUE)
text_separator <- "/r/n"
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
observeEvent(input$do, {
    splited_text <- strsplit(my_text, text_separator)
    responses_tags <- tagList()
    for(i in splited_text){
     check_elem <- substr(i, 1, 5)
     if(check_elem == "table"){
        num_table <-  as.numeric(substr(i, 6, nchar(i)))
        extracted_table <- fun_extract_table(num_table)
        cur_table <- paste0("my_table", num_table)
        print(cur_table)
        print(extracted_table)
        output[[cur_table]] <- renderTable(
          return(extracted_table)
        )
        responses_tags <- tagList(responses_tags, tableOutput(cur_table))
        print(responses_tags)
      }else{
        responses_tags <- tagList(responses_tags, shiny::tags$p(HTML(i)))
      }
    }
    output$docx_display <- renderUI(
      responses_tags
    )
  })
})
```

Ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("do", "Ok")
    uiOutput("docx_display")
  )
)
```

For the print I got the current result:

```
[1] "my_table1"
  Mon tableau TEST Test
1             test TesT
2             tESt TTTT
<div id="my_table1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
[1] "my_table2"
  Mon tableau 2 TEST 2 Test 2
1               Test 2 TesT 2
2               tESt 2 TTTT 2
<div id="my_table1" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
<div id="my_table2" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
```

I got different result for the shiny app:

[image: Shiny app results]

Can you help me and explain me why I don’t have my table 1 on the shiny app, please ?

Regards !

Comment: what is `selected_para`

Comment: selected_para is splited_text, I just edited it, thanks